# Jenkins build waiting for next available executor pending time

Tags: jenkins

I need to get the exact time when the build has triggered(`build periodically` option currently using). Because of the configuration only 3 tasks can run in parallel. Consider 3 tasks are running in parallel now. So the executor will be putting the next task in `Waiting for the next available Executor` state. So I need to access this waiting time or exactly when it is started as date means when its triggered.

I have used [Build Timestamp Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Timestamp+Plugin) also. But no use. It is giving the time when the build steps has started. So can anybody help me do this? Thanks.

Comment: Are your jobs taking too much time to execute and hence you don't have ant spare executor. Is this the case? And that's why you need to check when all these 3 jobs are triggered, specifically on which date?

Comment: updated the question. can you please check again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution which I'm going to share now. If anybody is in the same situation, this might help them.

```
build_details = get('http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/<jobName>/api/xml?tree=builds[id,queueId]&xpath=//build[id=<buildId>]')
queueId = build_details['build']['queueId']
queue_details = get('http://localhost:8080/jenkins/queue/item/<queueId>/api/json')
job_queued_time = Time.at(queue_details['inQueueSince'] / 1000.0).to_time.utc
```

`Note:` I've posted pseudo code, not a full solution. You have to port it to your language. `<jobName>`, `<buildId>`, `<queueId>` are variables, please replace them.

Here, `localhost:8080` is same for everyone because, that is going to run in Jenkins machine itself. Mostly my solution works for single node Jenkins(i.e. No `master-slave` architecture). I haven't tested it in `master-slave` though.